# Firebase restructure database automatically

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I currently have an app with about 200 users and I'm trying to restructure my firebase db without breaking functionality so I can expand to other schools. I plan on pushing a required update before doing so.

**Right now my database looks something like this**

/users/user

/otherproperty/object

**I am trying to move everything under one big "school" folder so it looks like this.**

school/users/user

school/otherproperty/object

**Is there a way I can change my firebase to look like this?**

Comment: What does your application code look like? Is it web? Or a native iOS/Android app? For a web app you can probably assume users will "instantly" be using the new code. But for a native app you will need to either force an upgrade or ensure your changes are backwards compatible, which typically means dual-writing for a while.

Comment: It is a iOS app made with Ionic Framework(AngularJS).

Answer (score 0):

You could implement Firebase realtime database triggers that would fire whenever any data is added/modified/deleted under the old data hierarchy that performed the same updates in the new data hierarchy.  You could also implement triggers that performed the same updates from the new hierarchy into the old hierarchy.

Then, you can migrate users from the old hierarchy into the new one at whatever rate/schedule makes the most sense to you.  The triggers would maintain data consistency between the two hierarchies.

Once all users are migrated to the new hierarchy, you can remove the triggers and move forward with only the new hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do with a relatively small amount of data is write a script to get a snapshot of the data and set it in the new path.

```
let userRef = firebase.database().ref('users')
let newUserRef = firebase.database().ref('MYSCHOOL/users')

userRef.on('value', function(usersSnapshot) {
  newUserRef.set(usersSnapshot.val())
});
```

You can also use the REST API and use [shallow queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#shallow) to grab the individual keys and query data in smaller chunks.